# post_max_size = 1024M, but only a half of $_POST data are received

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, post

my problem has not solved yet, i have php file with htlm for with a lot of variable including looping from database, i've increase post_max_size = 1024M in php.ini, n i make sure it in phpinfo(), but when i submit it, only a half of $_POST data are received. then i try to count the $_POST data with

```
$size = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
echo "$size";
```

and the result is..

```
15231
```

i don't know what the meaning of that number, but my questions is what wrong with my $_POST data? why not received all? really need your helps guys..

edited:
these are configuration in my php.ini..

```
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
memory_limit = 2048M
```

Comment: php's upload capabilities border on the moronic. it's not enough to just set the post_max_size. you need to have a memory_limit LARGER than the post limit. plus there can be limits on the max number of post variables allowed.

Comment: Marc B, as far as I know your memory limit depends on what you plan on doing with the file. If you're just storing the file, the memory limit doesn't need to match or be larger than the post_max_size. If you're loading the file into memory, say to manipulate an uploaded JPEG, you need to adjust your memory limit accordingly.

Comment: @wasis just try print_r($_POST) to see whats get displayed

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh : i did, it showed me the variables in array but not all, several are lost.

Comment: @MarcB: i did, check my update..

Comment: can you give your form code

Comment: <form name="SOAdd" action="adr-libraryadd.php?ID=<?php echo $_GET[bookID];?>" method="post">
<input name="type" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowLib["type"];?>" size=30 readonly>

it's almost 2000 row of my script if i want to copy it, i can just say, that the below form code those are not parse when i submit the form, i thought i was the post_max_size but not, i'm confuse what must i do.. please help..

Answer (score 0):

Just change in your php.ini file

post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1024M

Answer (score 0):

It's 1024 MB (1 GB) data you are trying to post
if this then chances  are less to upload the data because in that case some time you server will not support or browser will also face the issue.

Could you let us know what data you are trying to upload

Comment: i just click the submit button, post a text, not trying to upload file image or anything, but there are several data not posted, and the rest are posted, i thing it because to many data because the looping are many, then i set the post_max_size, but unfortunately no change..

Comment: please try to post small amount of data like then check it is working or not

Comment: Plz try to use other system and might be ur server is not working properly